# Android: Keeping a reference of a fragment inside a Service acceptable?

Tags: android, service, fragment

When I bind to a `Service` to retrieve the `Service` object, can I set a reference of a `fragment`(the place im binding the `Service` from) inside my `Service`? I just worried about memory leak problems.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private SomeFragment mFragment;
...

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        //cleanup
        mFragment = null;
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    public void setSomeFragment(SomeFragment fragment){
        mFragment = fragment;
    }
}
```

I do this so i can call methods from my `fragment` inside my `Service`. Thanks.

edit: To provide more context, this `Service` is not visible to outside apps.
There is only one client that binds on `onResume()` and unBinds on `onStop()`.

Comment: add mFragment = null; in some `unsetSomeFragment()` method, not in `onUnbind()`

Comment: Thanks, I'll put it in another method and call it from somewhere else.